# Change binding on event for button using jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-events

I've bound an event to an icon on click.  The event changes the id of a button on the page.  I want a new event to be bound to that new id, and the existing event bound to the old id to be unbound.  How do I do this?

I can see from Firebug that the button id successfully changes when the icon is clicked.  However, when I look at POST, I see that the hidden field with id "Final_Approval" has the value of "Approved", which tells me that the event tied to the original button id occurred, and I don't want it to.  All of my jQuery is inside document ready.

The original button:

```
<button id="btn-final-approval-no-review" class="btn btn-warning" type="submit">Final Approval</button>
```

The original event tied to that id:

```
$('[id^="btn-final-approval"]').click(function () {
    $("#Final_Approval").val("Approved");
});
```

The event triggered when the icon is clicked:

```
$("#add-vendor-item").click(function () {
   $('#btn-final-approval-no-review').attr('id', 'btn-vendor-rep-review2');
}
```

The new event I want to take place:

```
$("#btn-vendor-rep-review2").click(function () {
    $("#ItemRequestStatusId").val("@Portal.BusinessModel.Entities.ItemRequestStatusId.VendorRepReview");
});
```

Comment: **do not change the ID**, and do not expect event handlers bound on pageload to suddenly start working with an element that you just changed. It didn't match the selector at the time of binding, so it's not bound, period!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To bind events to elements that change dynamically, you need to use *delegation* with [`on()`](https://api.jquery.com/on/):

```
$(document).on('click', '[id^="btn-final-approval"]', function() {
    $("#Final_Approval").val("Approved");
});
```

As adeneo said, you probably shouldn't move IDs around, you should use classes. But the same idea applies, you just have to change the selector in the `on()` call.

Comment: I also added this to the click event tied to the original id.  I will rework my code to use class instead of id.

Answer (score 0):

Use on delegate to bind click event dynamically.

```
$("body").on("click","#btn-vendor-rep-review2", function () {    
    $("#ItemRequestStatusId").val("@Portal.BusinessModel.Entities.ItemRequestStatusId.VendorRepReview");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).on('click', '#finalApproval', function() {

if($(this).hasClass('first')){
    $(this).removeClass('first');
    //first action to be preformed    
}else{
  //second action to be preformed.
}


});
```

then simply add class `first` to the button on page load.

If you need it to toggle back you can just re-add the class `first` in the second action to be preformed area
**EDIT**

after re-reading the question you probably cant use `this` - just substitute with the id / class of the item in question and add the if/else statement to the handler for that item.